# My JRadioButton does not shows when I run but when I click on that area it shows

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8, jradiobutton

Hello Im facing this problem in netbeans 8.1 when I run my simple swing application. My frame shows only one radio button and for second radio button when I select on that area it shows and when I deselect it disappears.
Check the below images

[When I run my swing application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLs4P.png)

[When I click on the radio button area it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0yIf.png)

Source Code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
public class MainClass {
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JRadioButton radStudent,radTeacher;

public MainClass(){ //Constructor of main class
    prepareGUI();
}
public static void main(String arg[]){
    MainClass main = new MainClass();
}

private void prepareGUI(){ //GUI 
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Select any one");
    mainFrame.setSize(300,200);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    //Frame position set
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int height = screenSize.height;
int width = screenSize.width;
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //radio for employee
    radStudent = new JRadioButton("Student");
    radStudent.setBounds(10,10,100,20);

    //radio for Teachers
    radTeacher = new JRadioButton("Teacher");
    radTeacher.setBounds(110,10,100,20);

    mainFrame.add(radStudent);
    mainFrame.add(radTeacher);

}
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You need to `add()` components and _then_ call `setVisible()`.

Comment: `mainFrame.setVisible(true);` This should be done after all components are added, and straight after `pack()` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is: you have to understand that the JFrame is using a **[LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)** to organize the items you *add* to it.

Changing your code to

```
mainFrame.add(radStudent, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
mainFrame.add(radTeacher, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

will give you a frame that shows the one button on top; and the other on the bottom of the window (because, by default, JFrame uses a BorderLayout to organize its children).

In other words: as soon as you want to use more than one component, you have to sit down first and think up how to *organize* those components. And then you select that LayoutManager, for example [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) that provides the easiest way to get to that "structure" you decided to use.